# Disable "commit mention ..." settings for Git repo by default

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

For every repository there are two "commit mention" settings enabled by default.
[image]

Is there a way to disable one of these or both by default (per project or even org) when a new repo is created?

I did not find any project or org setting in the web ui. Can this maybe done using some rest api?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of manually changing these options you can use the very same API as the WebUI does:

Endpoint:

> [https://dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{PROJECT-ID}/_api/_versioncontrol/UpdateRepositoryOption?__v=5&repositoryId={REPO-ID}](https://dev.azure.com/%7BORG%7D/%7BPROJECT-ID%7D/_api/_versioncontrol/UpdateRepositoryOption?__v=5&repositoryId=%7BREPO-ID%7D)

Request Type:

```
POST
```

Payload:

```
{"key":"WitResolutionMentionsEnabled","value": <true|false>}
```

Project ID and REPO ID (hash values) can be extracted either using the Developer Tools in your browser or using the Python API Wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I searched and tried with the related REST API ([Repositories - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)) and Azure CLI ([az repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos?view=azure-cli-latest)), but did not find any available interface can change two option on repository settings.

Looks like, currently we have no available method to change the options of repository settings in batches. You may need to manually change these options.

If your projects really need this feature, I recommend that you can report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion). That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product team, and make it more convenient for the product team to collect and categorize your suggestions.